What is a "recent" investigation?
I am writing a doctoral thesis in philosophy (Europe) on an author who passed away in 1980. Over the past 20 years, there has been a significant volume of research on his thought. In my thesis, I sometimes need to refer to the "most recent" investigations in order to justify certain claims. However, I don't have any justified criterion to define what is considered "recent." I simply limit the research to the last 5 or 10 years because that is what is conventionally done.
Is there any text, book or author that explains how to define what "recent" means in academic research?
Thank you in advance.

You say you're referring to the "most recent", but that means something different from just plain "recent"; it's possible for the "most recent" thing to not be recent at all!  Exactly what term(s) are you using in your thesis?

'Recent' means 'after I started grad school'

@jwodder  I understand your point, and you are right. I simply wanted to refer to the freshest and latest research that has been done. That my criteria are relatively conventional and arbirtrary is something I already say in OP.

I wonder why you say you "need to" refer to "most recent" investigations and then you ask for the definition of what you just wrote. Is this wording from some regulations or official guidelines, e.g., of your department regarding doctoral theses?

@ChristianHennig Frankly, I don't understand your question. A doctoral thesis should ideally contrast its research with the latest publications that directly or indirectly address the research topic. The question here is how to demarcate 'the latest.' I think the question is fairly clear.

Well, you asked for the definition of a term in a way that made me wonder whether you wanted to know what the term used in some official context (i.e., PhD regulations of your university or the like) exactly meant. This doesn't seem to be the case, which is all fine, but I had seen questions of this kind before that were about understanding regulations and the like.

There is a point where we just need to take language as it is practiced. You want to define "recent" in "most recent investigations", but I think that's about as fruitful as wanting to define "investigations": The word means different things in different contexts and to different readers. But most experts in an area will understand the meaning of the word as it is used in that context. For example, "recent" in your context may be the last 20 years whereas someone writing on the "recent history of the universe" might mean the last 5 billion years. Similarly, someone talking about the history of writing on Shakespeare will use the word "investigations" differently (namely, as in "research on a topic") than someone considering the difference in police work depending on the race of the person being investigated (namely, as in "assessing facts and motives").
And these differences are all fine: Language is a way to communicate between people who have a shared cultural understanding of the use of words in a specific context. It is not necessary to define common words.

Thank you. This is the answer that most closely resembles my point of view, and is the one that seems most reasonable to me. I am simply annoyed that there are no more “objective” or less relative criteria to determine what is something recent academically.

@Ian Well, but that is true for almost every common-language use. I mean, is there an objective academic criterion for what "is" means? Or what "means" means? I'm sure philosophers and linguists have written whole books about it, but for the rest of us the issue is really not of great concern and we happily use the word in its common usage and understand each other just fine.

I guess you are right, could it be that I’m a philosopher?

I fully agree with Wolfgang. Not every word in a scientific paper is a term that needs precise definition. It's just common language, and you as the author decide where you want to be vague and where precise. If you are unsure yourself what the word means, choose another word. But I like the word recent because it lets me express something without the burden of proof.

Say, I write in the introduction something like "Studies of ... caught a lot of attention recently due to rapid developments in quantum computing." The only thing I want to say with this sentence is that I am writing about a hot topic. I don't really care if it's 5 or 10 years.

@Vosoni I think the same, I think it is an appropriate word. I understand that what you are suggesting is that what is recent is demarcated by the author's own authority, based on relatively subjective criteria that have to do with research.

Using relative terms in academic writing is a good way to cause confusion. You mention 'recent' as an example. Recent will have a different meaning for e.g. people who study the last ice age and those who study global warming. Hence relative terms should always be avoided. I once wanted to know the temperature variations in an area and found a paper with a title discussing 'recent temperature variations' in the area. The paper was from 1940 and not exactly what I was looking for.
Relative terms like recent, large, small, heavy, light and many more will always be judged by the reader's own perspective and experience. In all cases there is no standard on what is large, small etc. Similarly, 'recent' is just relative and can mean anything and, I would argue, is never possible to interpret in an absolute fashion. The recommendation is always to express values rather than relative terms but the use of the relative terms is tempting when you are deep into your own perspective.
So there is no definition of what 'recent' means.

Yes. Rephrase "recent research" to "research in the past 5 years" or something similar. Or even "research since 2019" to be more precise.

@JonCuster Perfect. But then, how do I justify that five- or ten-year cut?

@Peter Jansson Your solution is the most definitive. But we throw the baby in with the dirty waters. I would like to see a way to save the expression and at the same time be accurate.
I see frankly very normal in a thesis to use phrases like “in recent research on X, Y is justified...”

@Ian - how many papers do you need/want to bring up - that many years…

The meaning of "recent" and "most recent" can be very different. If something was published 100 years ago and nothing was done on this topic since then, this 100-year-old publication is still the most recent but no longer recent. In rapidly developing fields, something you refer to as "recent" in your preprint is no longer recent by the time your paper gets published, because things change faster than typical turnaround times of the journals.

Well, all you're saying is that the expression is relatively proportional. But based on what criteria is that relation or proportion made? Is it a convention or there is an objective criteria?

I would say there is no objective criterion for "recent", it expresses how you as an author feel about it. For an elderly professor something that happened 20 years ago could still feel recent, while for a young student everything that happened last semester is old. On the other hand, "most recent" is objective and can be proven using publication databases.

Much clearer now. And what is the criterion for the “most” recent ones? Obviously we are referring to the “latest” publications, but where do we demarcate what is “latest”? Also in a convention?

Well, you take all publications, order them chronologically, and the last ones will be the most recent. E.g. 5 most recent publications, independently of why (in absolute terms) they were published.
